# Javascript. It is possible to add id on splitted word?? using word.split("")

Tags: javascript

```
var wtc = document.getElementById("sw").value;
var cw = wtc.split("").join('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
cw.toString();
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.innerHTML=cw;
```

I have this code. how can i add id to the splitted(am i right on my term??) word.. it is possible?
I want is to add id on each letter that is splited. I dont know the exact number of letter because it's depend on the user's inputted word.

for example. i have this word from split.

```
[W][O][R][M]
```

i want it to be something it this. or anything that have an id :)

```
<div id="DIVtext1">W</div> 
<div id="DIVtext2">O</div> 
<div id="DIVtext3">R</div> 
<div id="DIVtext4">M</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you look into [Lettering.JS](http://letteringjs.com)

Comment: What are you going to do with those `<div>`s? I guess that giving them ids is not needed.

Comment: How about using a class and targeting the elements by index?

Comment: @Bergi what LetteringJS is used for is to apply simple transforms on individual letters/words (usually for titles etc), and it does it by doing almost exactly what the OP is asking for. It's a really small simple library that's pretty widely used.

Comment: i want each letter to be clickable. :)) if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean something like:

```
var word = "WORM".split("");
var demoEle = document.getElementById("demo");
for(var w = 0, len = word.length; w < len; w++) {
    var divEle = document.createElement("div");
    divEle.id = "DIVtext"+(w+1);
    divEle.onclick = (function(v) { 
        return function() { copyDiv( "DIVtext" + (v+1) ) };
    })(w);
    divEle.innerHTML = word[w];
    demoEle.appendChild( divEle );
}
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTuZR/)

Updated Demo:: [jsFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/PTuZR/2/)

Comment: I was just going to type up something like this. I'm happy to see not everyone jumps at adding external libraries.

Comment: @Sudhir can you please add this line?? onClick="CopyDIV(this.id)" please.. idk where to put this.. in each letter

Answer (score 0):

You could use a loop (`for(i=0;i<splittedArray;i++)`) and jQuery to add div tags to the dom with the innerHtml being the word.

Basically, once you have it in your array you can put it wherever you want.  I find that jQuery makes it easy; however, you could also do it through jscript alone.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved pretty easily using **[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/)**.

```
var letters = $('#sw').val().split('');

$.each(letters, function(i, letter) {
    $('<div />', {
        id: 'DIVtext'+ i,
        text: letter
    }).appendTo('#demo');
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2E6zk/)**

If jQuery isn't an option, here's what you can do with vanilla JS.

```
var letters = document.getElementById('sw').value.split(''),
    demo = document.getElementById('demo');

for(var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('div');

    letter.innerHTML = letters[i];
    letter.id = 'DIVtext'+ i;

    demo.appendChild(letter);
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uhukv/)**

Comment: one more question.. iwant it to be clickabe.. i want to put onClick. is it possible?

Comment: Yes, just add the line `letter.onclick = function() {};`